# MYSQL Auto increment categorized by field

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

Is there anyway i can set the auto increment value in MYSQL to increase itself by grouping itself by a field id? Such as

```
Shop_id | AI_Value
-------------------
1       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 1
3       | 1
1       | 3
```

Currently, im running a query to get the last row, and then insert by adding +1 to the value, which i assume is highly inefficient, and will have potential flaws, such as duplicated values

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Also, why tagged [tag:sql-server]?

Answer (score 0):

you can use an utility table that is made just to store one progressive number. When you retrieve next progressive number you must lock the table, get the number, add +1 and store it.

Answer (score 0):

MyISAM tables support [just that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html). You can have the `AUTO_INCREMENT` on a second column in the index, and it will increment only as per change to the first column.

Alas, this means you will have to use `MyISAM`, which is a downside in itself...